# Crear primer proyecto en Django

Tags: python, django

Hola necesito crear mi primer proyecto en Django pero cuando ejecuto el comando para la creación del proyecto obtengo el siguiente error:

```
C:\casa>django-admin startproject casa
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\Scripts\djang
o-admin-script.py", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3088, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3072, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
 packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3101, in 
_initialize_master_working_set working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
ws.require(__requires__)
File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 892, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pytz' distribution was not found 
and is required by Django
```

Soy un principiante en programación y jamás he usado framerworks de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Probaste instalando pytz con la consola con `pip install pytz`?

Comment: Lo he instalado y todo funciona bien muchas gracias

Comment: Lo he instalado y todo funciona bien muchas gracias

Comment: Buenisimo! Me alegro, ahí lo agrego como respuesta así puedes aceptarla y se da por cerrada la pregunta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el mensaje parece que te falta instalar pytz:

```
pip install pytz
```

Saludos!